# Two 12 volt batteries lowering reaches power

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I just added an extra deep cycle 12 volt battery to my camper. I used half inch 15ft  (or so) wire to connect the positive to the older batterys positive and the same for the negative. My older battery was reading 13.8 volts before I added in the second. Now not 45 mins later my battery monitor (which is connected to the older battery) has dropped to 13.0 Volts. 
And only 80% of battery life remaining. Why is it dropping??

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the new battery was not fully charged, so the old battery gave it some charge.  In any case, 13.8 volts is very high for a battery that is not on float charge, or very recently removed from charging.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Well I have solar panels that run into a change controller then run to the older battery. The charge controller changes when needed then sits in a float mode.t he charge controller said 13.8V as soon as I hooked up the batteries when installing. Does this mean that the 13.8 is ok?

Comment: Yes, 13.8 volts is OK, if the batteries don't need frequent watering.